# jQuery AJAX call returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a Stock Exchange jQuery fix for a website.

EDIT: It updates a ID/CLASS or input value on the webpage depending on the value returned.

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>load demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/datacall/demo.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( resp ) {
            $( '#div' ).val( resp.currency[0].amount );
        },
        error: function( req, status, err ) {
            console.log( 'Something went wrong', status, err );
        }
    });
    var end = parseInt($('#value').val());
    var newend = parseInt($('#div').val());
    var result = $( end * newend );
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#new').val( result );
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<div>

    <input type="hidden" value="2500" id="value" />

    <input type="hidden" value="" id="div">

    <input type="text" id="new" value="" readonly/>

    <input type="button" value="Change" id="clickme" />

</div>
```

Currently it is returning:

```
[object Object]
```

I have also tried returning it to a div with .text()

demo.json:

```
    { "currency" : [
  {
    "name" : "South Africa",
    "code" : "ZAR",
    "amount" : 0.14
  },
  {
    "name" : "America",
    "code" : "USD",
    "amount" : 0.64
  },
  {
    "name" : "Europe",
    "code" : "GBP",
    "amount" : 1.29
  }
] }
```

Please can someone tell me what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `console.log(resp)`, what does that give.

Comment: Show us the response, then we'll can help you.

Comment: Can we see the source for your `demo.json` page? And have you tried `console.log(resp);`?

Comment: It means, that `resp.currency[0].amount` actually returns an object. Try to figured it out with `console.log(resp.currency[0].amount)` and check, what data/object returns.

Comment: [Tried using it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtWZM/), seems to be working fine. Nothing seems to be wrong with your object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Create some global variables
var end = parseInt($('#value').val(), 10);
var newend = 0;
var result = 0;

$.ajax({
    url: '/datacall/demo.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {

        // Check the values in console
        console.log(resp.currency[0].amount);
        console.log(resp.d.currency[0].amount);

        $('#div').val(resp.currency[0].amount);
        newend = parseInt(resp.currency[0].amount, 10);
        result = end * newend;

        // No need to create a new jQuery object using $()
        // result = $( end * newend );
    },
    error: function (req, status, err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
    }
});

$('#clickme').click(function () {
    $('#new').val(result);
});
```

So the main issues here is:-

- You need to do all the `result` logic in the ajax success callback, as ajax is `asynchronous` and you always get the empty values for the `end` & `newend` variables.
- No need to do this `result = $( end * newend );` as it creates a new jQuery object instance and hence you are getting `[object Object]`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and help!

@palash

I have applied this onto my file and I get 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currency' of undefined 

on console.log(resp.d.currency[0].amount);

Comment: @VaughanThomas Ok that was only for the testing/debugging purpose, you can remove all the `console.log` codes..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233650/jquery-nested-ajax-calls-formatting

Answer (score 20):

[object Object] is basically an array

Try this code:

```
   success: function( resp ) {
       //$( '#div' ).val( resp.currency[0].amount );
       alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
    },
```

This *should* show you the array, which will give you the ability to better select the elements to output

Comment: After `JSON.stringify(resp)`, I get an object. What should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating the product inside `$()`

```
var end = parseInt($('#value').val());
var newend = parseInt($('#div').val());
var result = end * newend; // this $(end * newend) is probably what was wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
var end = parseInt($('#value').val());
var newend = parseInt($('#div').val());
var result = $( end * newend );
```

is being evaluated before the success of the ajax call.  it needs to be moved into the success block

Answer (score 0):

use the for loop like this code :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( "select[name='continue[matiere]']" ).change(function () {
      var matiereID = $(this).val();


      if(matiereID) {


          $.ajax({
              url: "{{ path('ajaxform') }}",
              dataType: 'Json',
              data: {'id':matiereID},
              type:'POST',
              success: function(data) {
                  $('select[name="continue[chapitre]"]').empty();
                  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                    student = data[i];  

                      $('select[name="continue[chapitre]"]').append('<option value="'+ student['id'] +'">'+ student['nom'] +'</option>');
                  };
              }
          });


      }else{
          $('select[name="continue[chapitre]"]').empty();
      }
  });
  </script>
```